# Anyone faced this this `Timestamp should always be non-negative or null.` error while publishing events to a kafka topic from flink app?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Getting this error while publishing messages to a kafka topic from a flink app.
The same code is working in our test environment with similar producer configuration but failing in production environment. I couldn't find the reason for this issue.

```
2022-04-15 16:51:37,228 thread="Sink: spend-limit-publisher-sink (2/2)#15" level=WARN  logger=o.a.f.r.t.Task - Sink: spend-limit-publisher-sink (2/2)#15 (d7b4646c840c3882bb784125393b484a) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid timestamp: -9223372036854775808. Timestamp should always be non-negative or null.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init>(ProducerRecord.java:74)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init>(ProducerRecord.java:97)
at com.ex******.streamplatform.sdk.kafka.flink.ProducerFunction$Tuple2ProducerFunction.apply(ProducerFunction.java:80)
at com.ex******.streamplatform.sdk.kafka.flink.ProducerFunction$Tuple2ProducerFunction.apply(ProducerFunction.java:72)
at com.ex******.streamplatform.sdk.kafka.flink.KafkaSerializationSchemaAdapter.serialize(KafkaSerializationSchemaAdapter.java:37)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:907)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:99)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.invoke(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:223)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:54)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:205)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:134)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:105)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:66)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:423)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:204)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:684)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:639)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:650)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:623)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using Timers and State?

Comment: @PiyushPatel Yes, I'm using ProcessingTimeTimer and states for some custom operations

Comment: Are you trying to write kafka ProducerRecords that include timestamps?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes. the app is using processing time timers for session windowing and some custom triggers. when the final sink tries to publish message, the above error is thrown.

Comment: Are you able to edit the question to show your code as a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue was because of lack of watermark at the sink. So the timestamp was defaulting to Long.MIN_VALUE (-9223372036854775808)

Fixed it by adding watermark

```
limitedStream1.union(limitedStream2)
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<String>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                    .withTimestampAssigner((id, streamRecordTimestamp) -> Instant.now().toEpochMilli()))
            .map(new DataMapper())
            .filter(new NotNull<>())
            .addSink(connectorFactory.createProducer(String.class, EventRecord.class));
```